# SimpleDateFormat behaves inconsistently

Tags: java, simpledateformat

See the following piece of code:

```
String timeString = "1980-01-01T14:00:00+0300";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date date2 = sdf.parse(timeString);

// sdf.getCalendar().get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));
```

now, I'm in a country that has `+2h` offset, `+1` daylight savings(at the moment).
If I run this code as it is, it will print

```
1980-01-01T13:00:00+0200
```

If I uncomment the line asking about the calendar's offset, the output of the program is

```
1980-01-01T14:00:00+0300
```

Any idea why is that happening, and how can I get a consistent output?

To avoid any more unclear things:
Since I'm handling some legacy code, java 8 is not an option. And yes, the key point here is WHY, and not what are the workarounds?
And there are 2 WHYs:

1. Why do i pass a +0300 TZ and by default i receive a +0200 one? (SimpleDateFormat should always use TimeZone.getDefault unless
   otherwise specified).
2. Why does it give a different answer just because I call a getter on it's calendar instance.

Comment: what's inconsistent in it? when you don't use offset, it gives you date as it is, and when you use it changes according to timezone.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava Calling a getter once shouldn't change the output of the format function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `Calendar#get` is not a simple getter, it looks like this:

```
public int  get(int field)
{
    complete();
    return internalGet(field);
}
```

where `complete` does this, according to the Javadoc:

> Fills in any unset fields in the calendar fields. First, the `computeTime()` method is called if the time value (millisecond offset from the Epoch) has not been calculated from calendar field values. Then, the `computeFields()` method is called to calculate all calendar field values.

I looked up the source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.complete%28%29), but the code is the same for the latest Java version too.

Comment: Yes I knew that. But that's just sort of "it does it because it does it". To me it definitely looks like a bug.

Comment: I would say, this is a debatable design decision. There is a reason why Java 8 has a new date and time API :)

Comment: This answer would be perfect with a small snippet how OP could change his code to avoid that `complete()` breaks his code (e.g. setting some specific fields on the calendar instance, etc.)

Comment: That does not explain it. `SimpleDateFormat.format()` actually also calls `Calendar.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

`sdf.parse` changes formatter's internal calendar zone offset to +0300

```
    System.out.println(sdf.getCalendar());
    sdf.parse(timeString);
    System.out.println(sdf.getCalendar());
```

you can see the difference at the end of output lines

```
... ,ZONE_OFFSET=7200000,DST_OFFSET=0]
... ,ZONE_OFFSET=10800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

`sdf.getCalendar().get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);` restores calendar's zone offset back to current timezone

Comment: The question is: why does it do that? My hunch is the following: Calendar has a reference to a timezone object. When parsing the date, no timezone can be determined from "+0300".  It just stores offset for 3 hours in the `ZONE_OFFSET` field of Calendar. The `get()` method internally computes all fields for a Calendar when it has not done that yet for all fields, including the `ZONE_OFFSET` field. Calendar uses the timezone it knows to calculate the offset and determines a different offset.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming this is the most exact answer. Actually, where I am now, as I also wrote in the initial post, I'm in a +2 offset, +1 dst zone. This is not reprezentable in any way in a SimpleDateFormat pattern. That's why we combine it as +3. But then still, somewhere there's a bug inside the whole internal processing that Calendar and SimpleDateFormat do, since the behaviour of transforming (+3 +0) in (+2 +1) or leaving it as it was should be consistent, and not affected by a get. Since I'm not modifying sdf in any way post creation, sdf.format(sdf.parse(txt)) should always be txt.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormate uses Calendar to create the Date. The Date-Object is created with the Timestamp, wich is Calculated in `java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime()`. There in Line 2789 the initial time zone is used (which got set `java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initializeCalendar(Locale)`). Thats why you see the wrong Timezone.

When you call `get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)` the Method `java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields()` is called, which uses the Timezone that was set initially.

I Guess this is a Bug.